# ASP.NET Core Testing - get NullReferenceException when initializing InMemory SQLite dbcontext in fixture

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, xunit, in-memory-database

I have a test fixture in which I initialize my SQLite in-memory dbcontext, shown below:

```
public static MYAPPDBContext Create()
{
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MYAPPDBContext>()
                    .UseSqlite("DataSource=:memory:")
                    .Options;
    var context = new MYAPPDBContext(options);

    context.Database.OpenConnection(); // this is where exception is thrown
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();

    return context;
}
```

When I call the Create() method, I get the following NullReferenceException:

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Microsoft.Data.Sqlite
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteRelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.<>c.<OpenConnection>b__15_0(DatabaseFacade database)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded, TState state)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.OpenConnection(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade)
   at MYAPPPlus.UnitTests.TestInfrastructure.MYAPPContextFactory.Create() in C:\websites\MYAPPPremier\tests\MYAPPPlus.UnitTests\TestInfrastructure\MYAPPContextFactory.cs:line 26
   at MYAPPPlus.UnitTests.TestInfrastructure.QueryTestFixture..ctor() in C:\websites\MYAPPPremier\tests\MYAPPPlus.UnitTests\TestInfrastructure\QueryTestFixture.cs:line 24
```

Any ideas on what might be happening?

FYI: I'm basing my code on the blog post at https://garywoodfine.com/entity-framework-core-memory-testing-database/, among other resources. 
Also, my fixture works just fine when using basic ef core inmemory database.

Comment: is sqlite3.dll in the bin folder?

Comment: also, I've always seen connections strings as data<space>source. "Data Source=:memory:"

Comment: @terrencep I believe you have identified the issue with the connection string. it is suppose to be `Data Source=` which looks like a typo in the article.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My bad. I had installed Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core version 3.0.0 when I needed version 2.2.6 and I had not installed Microsoft.Data.Sqlite 2.2.6, which I have since installed. It's working now.

Also, FYI: both .UseSqlite("Data Source=:memory:") and .UseSqlite("DataSource=:memory:") work.

Comment: Can you share *why* you needed that version? I'm also having an NPE when opening a Sqlite connection (without Entity Framework)

Comment: I had the same issue and it worked after I installed nuget package Microsoft.Data.Sqlite. Thanks a lot for sharing the answer.

Answer (score 34):

I encountered this problem while trying to do EF Core scaffolding for an Sqlite database. The problem was that I had installed `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core` rather than `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`.

I uninstalled the former package, and ran this command:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite -Version 3.1.2
```

Then everything worked.
Yup...

Comment: I run into the same problem, this worked for me too, thank you very much. Does anyone know what happen with this two nuget packages? They have nearly the same description...

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue when trying to open `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection`, it was throwing `System.NullReferenceException` as well. The class which was initializing the connection was in library project referencing:

- `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` - v3.1.2
- `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core` - v3.1.2

Executable in this case was `NUnit` test, located in test project. Test project did not have `Sqlite` NuGet packages referenced, but it had a project reference to the library containing database logic. While building the test project some `Sqlite` dlls where copied to `bin` directory, although not all of them, which in the end turned out to be an issue. Adding reference to both `Sqlite` NuGet packages in the test project solved the issue.

Comment: This was helping me a lot! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there was a typo in the article.

The `DataSource` alias does not work here, you have to use `"Data Source=:memory:"` (with a space)

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MYAPPDBContext>()
    .UseSqlite("Data Source=:memory:") //<-- Note the space
    .Options;
```

Reference [Configuring a DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext)