# new SqliteConnection("Filename=:memory:"); gives System.NullReferenceException on connection.Open();

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, xunit

I have looked at the example for using SQLite in-memory databases to test an EF Core application from Microsoft.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/sqlite#using-sqlite-in-memory-databases

However calling `connection.Open();` for `var connection = new SqliteConnection("Filename=:memory:");` gives the exception

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'

Same result for `var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=:memory:");`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9173503/3850405

[image]

[image]

what am I missing?

```
public class QuestionUpdateTest: IDisposable
{

    private readonly DbConnection _connection;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context = null;
        
    public ChoiceSequencingQuestionUpdateTest()
    {
        var dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                        .UseSqlite(CreateInMemoryDatabase())
                        .Options;
                        
        _connection = RelationalOptionsExtension.Extract(dbContextOptions).Connection;

        _context = new ApplicationDbContext(dbContextOptions);
    }
    
    private static DbConnection CreateInMemoryDatabase()
    {
        var connection = new SqliteConnection("Filename=:memory:");

        connection.Open();

        return connection;
    }

    public void Dispose() => _connection.Dispose();
    
    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by installing NuGet `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` and not only `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core`. Very poorly documented and no build errors with the other package. Credit to @ShahinDohan.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60354061/3850405